# Perl Sort HoAoH/Scalar

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash, scalar

Im trying to sort a HoAoH/Scalar, ignoring scalar entries at the beginning and just sorting the sub HASHes based on key.

**From**

```
$out = {
  'bgp 65000' => [
    ' undo synchronization',
    ' graceful-restart',
    ' peer 192.1683.0.1 as-number 65000',
    ' #',
    {
      ' ipv4-family vpn-instance client2' => [
        '  import-route direct route-policy BURrail'
      ]
    },
    '#'
    {
      ' ipv4-family vpn-instance internet' => [
        '  default-route imported',
        '  import-route direct',
        '  import-route static'
      ]
    },
    ' #',
    {
      ' ipv4-family vpn-instance client1' => [
        '  import-route direct route-policy BURrail'
      ]
    },
    ' #',
  ]
};
```

**To**

```
$out = {
  'bgp 65000' => [
    ' undo synchronization',
    ' graceful-restart',
    ' peer 192.1683.0.1 as-number 65000',
    ' #',
    {
      ' ipv4-family vpn-instance client1' => [
        '  import-route direct route-policy BURrail'
      ]
    },
    ' #',
    {
      ' ipv4-family vpn-instance client2' => [
        '  import-route direct route-policy BURrail'
      ]
    },
    '#'
    {
      ' ipv4-family vpn-instance internet' => [
        '  default-route imported',
        '  import-route direct',
        '  import-route static'
      ]
    },
    ' #',
  ]
};
```

I have written code to sort on the keys of the HASHES but was after a way to just sort the data structure on the fly.

```
use Sort::Naturally;

$key = ( sort keys %{ $out[0] } )[0];
foreach $key1 ( @{ $out[0]{$key} } ) { 
    if ( ref($key1) eq 'HASH' ) { 
        push @sorted, ( ( sort keys %{$key1} )[0] );
    } else {
        print "$key1\n";
    }   
}
foreach $key1 ( nsort(@sorted) ) { 
    print "$key1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky! (Because it's silly. You should be using a more convenient data structure. Anyway...)

First, let's ignore the irrelevant. We want to sort the elements of an array, so let's locate that array.

```
for my $array (values(%$out)) { ... }
```

Along the same lines, let's create a "view" that contains only the elements we want to sort. The following gives the indexes of the elements we want to sort:

```
my @idxs = grep { ref($array->[$_]) } 0..$#$array;
```

So the following is the "view" (array slice) we want to sort:

```
@{$array}[ @idxs ]
```

Each of these elements is a reference to a hash. We'll want to naturally sort the only key of the referenced hash. The key can be obtained using the following:

```
( keys(%$_) )[0]
```

Now, we just need to assemble the blocks.

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natkeysort );

for my $array (values(%$out)) {
   my @idxs = grep { ref($array->[$_]) } 0..$#$array;

   @{$array}[ @idxs ] =
      natkeysort { (keys(%$_))[0] }
         @{$array}[ @idxs ];
}
```

Comment: pretty much exactly what I was thinking, except I didn't see the real need for natural sort (unless there actually are client10, etc)

Comment: Using a real view: `my $view = sub { \@_ }->( @{$array}[ @idxs ] ); @$view = natkeysort { (keys(%$_))[0] } @$view;`

Comment: @ysth, simplified a bit.

Comment: Thanks ikegami, that works perfectly. Do you have a suggestion for a better data structure? I need to keep sub elements (scalars) in the order i read from a config file but have the ability to group, basically a tree structure. Hence the array hash combination.

Comment: It's unclear what the significance of `#` and the relative placement of them to the hashes, so I can't recommend anything. This could even be considered of of the problems of the current structure.

Comment: The ` # ` is a 'section' separator in a network switch configuration file so its not part of my DS structure its just another scalar value in the array.  Because your solution just swaps the HASHes around the ` # `'s stay in the correct position.

Comment: If its not part of your "DS" structure, why is it part of your data structure?

Comment: @ikegami, many thanks, I have removed my correction.  your solution does work, I had a referencing issue.